# how to confine number of threads scipy.integrate.odeint use

Tags: python, scipy

I am going to use specify the number of threads that scipy.integrate.odeint use, but by default it use all available threads of the system, if it can parallel the integration.
Do you have an idea?

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
sol = odeint(derivate, x0, t)
```

The documentation of the [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) did not mention anything about it.
It is also possible to use environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`. I am just looking a method inside the python code.

Comment: `os.setenv('OMP_NUM_THREADS', '1')` or so?

Comment: it is also possible, but what if I have larger program that need to use different number of thread in each part?

Comment: You can call `os.setenv` any number of times, but I see your concern if you have to do it simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in pure python because under the hood the python calls C which then in turn calls Fortran where the actual logic resides